Second derivatives with implicit equation
I have a question about a video on Khan Academy. In this video, he solves a problem that looks like this:

Consider the curve given by the equation $y^3 - xy = 2$. It can be
shown that $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y}{3y^2-x}$.
Evaluate $\frac{d2y}{dx^2}$ at the point on the curve where x = -1 and
y = 1.

He then goes on to use the quotient rule and the chain rule on the first derivative $\frac{y}{3y^2-x}$  to get the expression:
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{\frac{dy}{dx}(3y^2-x)-y(6y*\frac{dy}{dx}-1)}{(3y^2-x)^2}$$
I understand everything at this point, but then he calculates the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ by putting the x- and y-values into the first derivative expression $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y}{3y^2-x}$ and inputting it into the second derivative expression along with the x- and y-values.
What I am confused about is that I thought the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in the second derivative expression represented the second derivative, and that you would need to solve the equation for the $\frac{dy}{dx}$, as you would do when calculating the first derivative of an implicit equation.
Can anyone help me understand what I am getting wrong?

Since we already have explicit expression for $\frac{dy}{dx}$, we can just differentiate it to get $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$. There is not need to solve it for $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$. And,  $\frac{dy}{dx}$ does not represent the second derivative, it's still the first derivative.

$\frac{dy}{dx}$ denotes the first derivative, not the second. The second derivative is denoted by $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$. The $\frac{dy}{dx}$s that show up in the second derivative calculation occur because they are differentiating the first derivative expression with respect to $x$, not $y$, so when they differentiate the terms with $y$, they get $\frac{dy}{dx}$, not $1$.
